# HTTPResponse hangs on multiple requests

Tags: c#

I have the following code to download a set of files from the HTTPServer. It gives the response for first couple of files and later gets stuck in getting the response. I could verify this from the log file that I create. In the log file, it writes "Before webresponse" but never reaches to "After webresponse" for the third file. I am already making use of using for webresponse. What could be wong here?

```
            Logger.WriteToLog("url = " +url);
            // Create a request to the file we are downloading
            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            webRequest.Timeout = 120000;
            webRequest.ReadWriteTimeout = 300000;

            // Set default authentication for retrieving the file
            //webRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(GlobalVariables.username, GlobalVariables.password);
            webRequest.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

            // Retrieve the response from the server
            Logger.WriteToLog("Before webresponse");
            using (HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse())
            {
                Logger.WriteToLog("After webresponse");

                // Ask the server for the file size and store it
                //Int64 fileSize = webResponse.ContentLength;

                // Open the URL for download 
                using (Stream strResponse = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    // Create a new file stream where we will be saving the data (local drive)
                    strLocal = File.Create(destFilePath);

                    // Loop through the buffer until the buffer is empty
                    while ((bytesSize = strResponse.Read(downBuffer, 0, downBuffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        if (isPaused)
                            waitRun_m.WaitOne();

                        if (isCanceled)
                            break;

                        strLocal.Write(downBuffer, 0, bytesSize);
                        // Invoke the method that updates the form's label and progress bar
                        UpdateProgessCallback(mediaName, bytesSize);
                    };

                    strResponse.Close();
                }

            }
```

Comment: destFilePath should be different on ecach response or you can have some file locks problems.

Comment: Yes. destFilePath is different on each response.

Comment: Close the files after write too. strLocal.Close(); You are creating files Allways, perhaps would be better to create the files only when you have a response (im just trying to improve the code, the answer could be a bit different).

Comment: Can be the problem the third file? What are the sizes of the files? Can you change the order of the files to see if it's stuck on different file?

Comment: Yes, for the first two files, it receives the resposne. I think as per HTTP protocol it allows only two requests from a client to a server.

Comment: Then it could be a server configuration (max allowed connections). Can you check the configuration?

Comment: Yes. It is the server configuration. It does not allow more than two concurrent connections. But the question is since I have used "using" contruct for response. Once the file is downloaded, it should free the response for the next connection.

Comment: But perhaps you are openning new connections without know if you have closed at least 1 connection. You need to pool the connections (max 2 connections to the server).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried ServicePoint class methods and it is working fine now. What I did was that after adding a readwritetimeout for webrequest, i assigned a name to the connection group using the statement:

webRequest.ConnectionGroupName = some_name;

and when closing a connection did:

webRequest.ServicePoint.CloseConnectionGroup(some_name);